# What is the AutoFac InstancePerLifetimeScope() in Unity?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, unity-container, autofac

I need to port a part an application that was made with Autofac implementation but we decide change this in our app to Unity.

We dont know what is the correct lifetime Manager in Unity to substitute in instead of Autofac InstancePerLifetimeScope.

Answer (score 0):

The equivalent of `Autofac`'s `BeginLifetimeScope` in `UnityContainer` is `container.CreateChildContainer()`. Edit: The reason I mention this is that understanding this is crucial to understanding the implication of changing the LifetimeManager.

If you want that `ChildContainer` to resolve to a new instance, then you register the instances as `HierarchicalLifetimeManager` (as opposed to the `ContainerControlledLifetimeManager`)